# sharedApplication is unavailable

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm trying to access my core data from the watch kit extension but i'm unable to use the shared application because it's not available in watch kit. How do I initialize the `managedObjectContext` within my view controller without using the shared application code?

```
    if (self.managedObjectContext_ == nil) {
    self.managedObjectContext_ = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
```

right now, it's assuming my `managedObjectContext` is nil.

Comment: You can move core data initialization out of your app delegate, there's no reason it has to be in there, it's just where Apple puts it by default

Comment: how do I initialize it in the view controller? Will it still access the same core data if I initialize it outside the app delegate?

Comment: As long as you move all Core Data initialization methods from the app delegate and they write to the same file then it should work the same. It might make things easier to do this in a custom NSObject subclass instead of your view controller. Note that you will need to do a bit of extra work to share the data between both apps, see this for reference http://www.makeandbuild.com/blog/post/watchkit-with-shared-core-data